# Rails 5 error: XMLHttpRequest.response is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, xmlhttprequest, ruby-on-rails-5, actionpack

Given a partial view that simply turns a given ruby object into JSON, shouldn't `render 'ajax/object'` and `render json: @object` deliver the same result?

ajax/object.json.erb:

```
<%= @object.to_json %>
```

@object:

```
{&quot;id&quot;:1}
```

Because they don't.

`render 'ajax/object'` results in `XMLHttpRequest.response === null` and the rendered view being sent as: (Snippet taken from saved .har file)

```
      "content": {
        "size": 18,
        "mimeType": "application/json",
        "compression": -11,
        "text": "{&quot;id&quot;:1}"
      },
```

`render json: @object`, on the other hand, results in the behavior I expected: `XMLHttpRequest.response === ("id": 1)`

So my question is: Is this difference in rendering behavior a bug and, if not, what is the purpose of `render 'ajax/object'`'s rendering behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the string created in the template is HTML escaped.

While you could fix it with:

```
<%= raw( @object.to_json ) %>
```

Using a template is stupid and silly in the first place. Rails has to lookup the template by traversing a tree of possible files and then has to parse ERB and create a string buffer etc. This is just ridiculously inefficient for something which can be handled by passing an object to a JSON encoder.

Comment: If you want a slow JSON templating language there is always jBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realized that the template was inefficient and intended to change it. I just didn't understand why it didn't work at all.

Comment: There's huge xss vulnerabilities possible with just converting an object to JSON on a web page.

Comment: @justingordon how so? If you are just passing data from your controller to a view and calling `.to_json` on it there is no specific XSS vulnerability - you are doing the exact same thing as `render json: @object` but in a really convoluted way.